# Azure role configuration management

Tags: configuration, azure, web-config, app-config

I don't see how Windows Azure lets you vary the configuration of an application when you have no choice but to hold configuration settings in web.config (or app.config).

For example...

Quite often projects will make use of a 3rd party library that makes heavy use of web.config. The use of web.config may involve connection strings, app settings or custom configuration sections. A good example of this is ELMAH. A web.config file for ELMAH might look like the following:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="MyElmahDatabase"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=tcp:myServer.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDB;User ID=user@myServer;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="MyElmahDatabase" />
  </elmah>

</configuration>
```

There are a couple of problems here:

- There is no way for me to update or vary whether remote access is enabled between Service Configurations.
- There is no way for me to update or vary the ELMAH connection string between Service Configurations.

This is because the web.config is packaged as is into the .cspkg file and ELMAH will not look at the Service Configuration settings (which are the only way I can vary configuration settings between Service Configurations).

I can think of many other examples where this is a problem...

- Any data access frameworks that look directly at the connection strings section.
- Any custom configuration settings I need to create.

...to name just two.

Am I missing something or is this a significant gap in the configuration management offered by Windows Azure?

## EDIT

From the answer and comments below, it looks like this is something that is not well supported. I think that managing multiple solution build configurations to support different configuration profiles is a very weak solution. I should not have to rebuild the solution for each configuration profile I need (there will likely be quite a few). Compilation is not equal to configuration.

I was wondering if there was a way to modify the .cspkg file as it is just a zip file. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj151532) documentation you can on Linux.

I've looked at the manifest in the .cspkg file and it looks like this:

```
<PackageManifest version="2">
  <Encryption keytype="1" />
  <Contents hashtype="1">
    <Item name="MyApp.Web.UI_<GUID>.cssx" hash="AED69299C5F89E060876BC16BD3D6DE5130F6E62FFD2B752BAF293435339B7E2" uri="/MyApp.Web.UI_<GUID>.cssx" />
    <Item name="MyApp.Web.Services_<GUID>.cssx" hash="7AC81AFF642E4345173C8470C32A41118A4E3CFD4185B82D0ADA44B71057192D" uri="/MyApp.Web.Services_<GUID>.cssx" />
    <Item name="SMPackage_<GUID>.csmx" hash="B5E6B83B62AF64C7C11CAC1A394ABBF15D7DB7667A773C5284CE5BE95C5834E9" uri="/SMPackage_<GUID>.csmx" />
    <Item name="SDPackage_<GUID>.csdx" hash="F34B7C02A551D82BAD96881E2DA9447D0014D49B47CCB3840475BDC575234A7D" uri="/SDPackage_<GUID>.csdx" />
    <Item name="NamedStreamPackage_<GUID>.csnsx" hash="FA2B5829FF5D9B2D69DCDDB0E5BDEE6B8B0BC09FFBF37DAEEE41CF3F3F4D0132" uri="/NamedStreamPackage_<GUID>.csnsx" />
  </Contents>
  <NamedStreams>
    <Stream name="RequiredFeatures/MyApp.Web.Services/1.0" />
    <Stream name="RequiredFeatures/MyApp.Web.UI/1.0" />
    <Stream name="SupportData/MyApp.Web.Services/1.0" />
    <Stream name="SupportData/MyApp.Web.UI/1.0" />
  </NamedStreams>
</PackageManifest>
```

Unfortunately, if I re-compute the hash of the unchanged "MyApp.Web.UI_.cssx" file, my hash is different from the one in the manifest.

Hash from manifest: AED69299C5F89E060876BC16BD3D6DE5130F6E62FFD2B752BAF293435339B7E2

My calculated hash: E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855

Note that I have not yet changed the file, so the hash should be the same.

This suggests I'm calculating it wrong. My method was as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open))
        {
            ComputeHash(new SHA256Managed(), fs);
        }
    }

    private static void ComputeHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(stream);
        string hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
        Console.WriteLine(hashString.Replace("-", string.Empty));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The documentation link above, suggests it is straightforward to re-calculate the hash (on Linux anyway).

Does anyone know how to re-compute the hashes?

Comment: You can use .cscfg files for any configurables for your package.

Comment: That won't work - ELMAH (and other frameworks) won't look at configuration data held in .cscfg.

Comment: Well as far as my knowledge goes, only possible method of configuration for azure package is .cscfg files. For the frameworks like ELMAH you might have to find a workaround like changing configuration dynamically. But i think there are many experts of azure on Stackoverflow who might have much better answer to offer. Also this is a very interesting and important question.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a `Stream` to `ComputeHash()` ends up with a different hash as compared to using the `byte[]` overload. I don't know why.

Try something like:

```
private static void ComputeHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Stream stream)
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream)
    byte[] hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash( reader.ReadBytes( (int)stream.Length ) );
    string hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
    Console.WriteLine(hashString.Replace("-", string.Empty));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This will give you the hash you're after.

As you've probably already discovered, on linux you can get the digest with

```
openssl dgst -sha256 /path/to/file
```

Comment: this was not necessary as of today. Both old and proposed solutions gave me the same hash on .Net 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I you have items in your web.config that you want to change depending on how it's being built, there is a solution that is outside of Azure that you can use.  You can use [Web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).  These transforms are tied to your build configuration not your service configuration, but your service configurations a likely closely tied to your build configurations anyway (...Local.csfg -> Debug, ...Cloud.csfg -> Release).  If the default build configurations don't work for you, just create the ones you need.

If you want to use different service definitions per service configuration, then it's not supported by the UI, but you can [mess around with the build process to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440196/17089)

Comment: That could technically work but I'd have to start maintaining build configurations for each environment. This list might be long (dev, integration, system test, UAT, production) and each additional build configuration must be built which adds to the build time. I would like to have a Debug build and a Release build and be able to deploy either of those to any environment.

Comment: Regardless of what solution you use, if you want a different web.config for each environment you will have to do a build per environment anyway as the web.config is included as part of the package.  The package can't be altered once created.

Comment: I'm not sure that is entirely true - under the "Debug" build configuration I can have "n" number of Service Configurations. By default these are "Local" and "Cloud", would be great if I could have "Local", "Cloud-Integration", "Cloud-SystemTest", "Cloud-UAT" etc. And that I could vary the configuration files for each of those Service Configurations. I don't see why I should have to rebuild the entire solution just to cope with additional configuration profiles - compilation is not equal to configuration.

Comment: I think we might be talking at cross purposes so let me take a step back.  Your question was about web.config settings and their relationship to service configurations.  Currently there is none and I don't see that changing anytime soon.  If your hope was to have some sort of external web.config like the .cscfg where you can create just one package and provide a different config that won't work with Azure because when the package is created the web.config is included in the package.  You can't just open the package and alter it because it's signed and check summed so any changes invalidate it

Comment: As annoying as it is, if you want a different web.config for each environment you will have to do a build per environment.